# webUSB Relay Driver hardware

Tags: webusb

Over the last couple of years I have been looking for an easy way to control a few relays from Javascript.  I want to build a web App to control starting sequence horns for sailing races.

I recently discovered webUSB and it seems like exactly what I need.   A direct connection from JS in chrome to the USB world. Simple coding in a language I already use.

On the hardware side I am having trouble finding a product that is compatible.   Googling USB Relay finds 100's of products that all seem to rely on some proprietary SW  for the OS. I can find lots of educational demo's that turn an LED on and off.

Does anyone have any ideas where to find such a product?

Comment: could you please elaborate on how USB, web and relays are connected to each other in your project and how it could be related to StackOverflow? I'm sure that USB is not required here at all... And StackOverflow is a good place to accumulate questions and answers which are related to software engineering. Please edit your question to add extra information to avoid your question being deleted.

Comment: I apologize if I have messed up.

Comment: I will try to explain why i posted here.  In my search for find an easy way to make a web application that could control some hardware, I ran into webUSB, a software update to the chrome browser which appears to allow javascript to send and receive data thru a USB connection to a USB device.  I haven't been able to find a source for a simple USB Relay that mentions webUSB support.  I did find a bunch of active threads on webUSB in Stack overflow. I was hoping that community could some light on why that might be.  Eg webUSB is a deadend or it's too new or I am just looking in the wrong places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm sure you will be able to find USB relays that can be controlled via WebUSB, most USB relays will probably come with some kind of serial port driver, e.g. https://numato.com/product/1-channel-usb-powered-relay-module uses a CDC serial port driver. These can be controlled using Web Serial, available in Chrome 77 and later behind a feature flag. For a tutorial, see https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/web-serial/

- Explainer: https://github.com/WICG/serial/blob/gh-pages/EXPLAINER.md
- API docs: https://wicg.github.io/serial/

If you search for "5V USB Relay Programmable Computer Control For Smart Home" on eBay, you will also find low-cost relays that use HID instead. The advantage of these is that you don't need any serial port or USB drivers, as it will use the operating system's built-in HID drivers. For that you can use WebHID. For more info, see https://github.com/robatwilliams/awesome-webhid.

Comment: Thank you,   This seems to be pointing me in the right direction.   It appears, the Browser police haven't come up with a universal solution yet.   Will report back if I have success.

Comment: I don't think there will ever be a universal solution. WebUSB, WebHID and Web Serial are great new web standards for addressing all the different ways in which devices can talk to computers. You can blame Microsoft for making it really hard to get USB drivers working properly.